# Subterranean Intelligent Species

Tags: science-based, creature-design, aliens, science-fiction

So this is a species that developed on a hostile planet. The planet's sun is brutal during the day, so the creatures developed in the winding caves beneath, (which are there for another reason) but mostly in the caves closer to the surface in order to exploit the planet's milder night cycle. As such, they are small, hunched creatures that developed powerful, complex eyes to take advantage of low light conditions, for example.

Are there any other features of subterranean creatures that might be added for more believability? Keep in mind the heat and radiation of the star.

Comment: I'm sorry, what are you asking?

Comment: Either as TrEs-2b, I don't understand your question, or it sounds really broad. Could you be more clear on that?

Comment: I apologize. I'm new and still learning exactly how all this works. I was asking for input mostly. I'll be more specific in the future. EDIT: I made the inquiry clearer.

Answer (score 1):

They would have white skin and hair due to their low exposure to the sun. If the caves are not very big or there are only a few big "halls", they would probably evolve a keen sense of hearing as well to hear something approach before they can see it through a bend in the tunnel.

A lot depends on their nutrition as well. Humans are fundamentally herbivores (more or less), a species that has to hunt (no light -> no plants) would evolve differently (in fact, any bipedal species will generally be slower than a quadrupedal one), so keep that in mind if they can not eat lots outside at night.

Obviously, they'd be active at night rather than in the day.

I suppose they would be better at orienting themselves in the maze-like cave structure.

Assuming that they exit the caves before it is completely dark they may evolve a second pair of eyelids, which are half-transparent to protect their hyper-sensitive eyes from the light during dusk/dawn.